# JSF, AJAX, updating dynamic table with selectOneMenu

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

I'm quite new to jsf, and I stuck in updatig table with ajax.

I need to have a table working toghther with select menu, the table needs to be refreshed onchange.
The table's columns depend on the menu value, columns number can be different for each value.

My code:

```
<h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenu"  value="#{reservationGuestBean.currentPremiseId}" >
            <f:selectItems value="#{reservationGuestBean.premiseNames}" var="p" itemLabel="#{p.label}" itemValue="#{p.value}" />
            <a4j:ajax event="change" listener="#{reservationGuestBean.premiseChanged}" ajaxSingle="true" render=":currentPremiseId, :reservationsHeading, :reservationsBody" />
        </h:selectOneMenu> 
    </h:form>
    <div><h:outputText id="currentPremiseId" value="PremiseId: #{reservationGuestBean.currentPremiseId}" /></div>
    <table id="reservationsTable">
        <tr>
            <ui:repeat id="reservationsHeading" var="col" value="#{reservationGuestBean.reservationTableHeading}">
                <th>#{col}</th>
            </ui:repeat>
        </tr>
        <ui:repeat id="reservationsBody" var="row" value="#{reservationGuestBean.reservationTableRows}">
            <tr>
                <ui:repeat id="reservationsRowContent" var="cell" value="#{row}">
                    <td>#{cell.value}</td>
                </ui:repeat>
            </tr>
        </ui:repeat>
    </table>
```

With the code I'm able to reload div's content, but not the table, neither heading nor content.
In firebug I can see update requests with desired response (xml with ), but selected table elements are not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty answer is just to wrap your table in an `h:panelGroup`, and use its id on the render tag of `a4j:ajax`:

```
<h:panelGroup id="myTable">
    <table>
    ...
    </table>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Having said that, you probably want to learn to use the component `h:datatable` instead of redering the table yourself using `ui:repeat`.

It's easy to use, and it will be a meaningful component in the JSF View, which plain HTML table is not (and that's why you can't just rerender it in the ajax tag). You can start by doing [the examples in this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html).